# Ms Access: How do I populate a table using a field in a form?

Tags: database, forms, ms-access-2010

I want to populate a table in Access that I've just created. I gave it 6 columns. I also made a form that has 6 field inputs. But now I'm confused as to how exactly you make the form write to the table. I want the table to populate downwards, not just re-updating one row every time (in a previous attempt I managed to have the fields save over the same row, but this isn't what I want). I can provide any extra info as needed.

Answer (score 3):

The Record Source property of your form should be set to the name of your table and Allow Additions set to Yes. The Control Source property of each field on your form should be set to the required column name.

You can create an Add New Record button on your form using the new button wizard, select Categories: Record Operations & Actions: Add New Record.

That is the bare minimum to start creating new records in your table from a new form.

Comment: I tried your answer and it is simply updating the one row it created. It is not adding a new row each time the button is clicked. Why is this? I used the wizard by selecting Record Operations --> Add New Record.